# VSCode cannot locate packages in unit tests

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, python-unittest, importerror

I've got a project with a suite of Python unit tests (using the unittest framework) that import Pytorch and cv2.
I am able to run them all from the command line with

`python -m unittest discover -s tests/`

But get import errors in the VSCode UI when I try to load them:

```
Failed to import test module: test_overlays
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "XXX\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\unittest\loader.py", line 436, in _find_test_path
    module = self._get_module_from_name(name)
  File "XXX\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\unittest\loader.py", line 377, in _get_module_from_name
    __import__(name)
  File "XXX\tests\test_overlays.py", line 13, in <module>
...
    import torch
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torch'
```

My project is structured as a "wrapper application" importing utilities from a core library:

```
main_proj/
   library/
      packages and modules importing torch
   tests/
      unit tests for the application
```

The tests generally test only the wrapper application (there are separate tests for the library), but I occasionally import modules from `library/`.

Because the tests are outside `main_proj/library`, I need to add the library explicitly to the path at the top of each unit test:

```
import unittest
import sys
import os, os.path

sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'library'))
```

Why does this arrangement work just fine from the command line, but not from VSCode?

Comment: Can [docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/testing) help?

Comment: I seem to be doing everything described there.  Where do I begin looking for this failure?  Is it possible something is masking the tests?  Why should this work from the command line and not from VSCode?

Comment: I reproduced it according to your directory structure, but I didn't encounter similar problems. I think this may be a bug. You can create an issue in [GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python) to submit the problem

Comment: I was getting this issue also with the cv2 package.  What ultimately works is to roll back to a Python 3.6/Pytorch 1.4 virtual environment (Ctrl+Shift+P Choose Interpreter), close VSCode, go into ~/.vscode and delete all Python extensions, then re-open VScode and reinstall the Python extension.

Sounds like there's some sort of bug here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What resolved this issue was to:

1. Update VSCode to the latest version
2. Switch to an older Python 3.6 Anaconda environment (Ctrl+Shift+P, then Choose Interpreter...) -- I'm not sure this step is necessary
3. Close VSCode
4. Delete the Python extensions and reinstall them:

   - From git bash:

     ```
     cd ~/.vscode/extensions
     rm -fr *python*
     ```
   - Re-open VSCode and navigate to the extensions panel (Cog wheel->Extensions) and search for Python)

Afterward, I was able to use my Python 3.8+Torch 1.12 environment without any hitches.

It seems that something between VSCode and the Python extensions can occasionally get corrupted and requires a clean start in order to recover.

Answer (score 0):

I had this myself today in a similar way. Test discovery could not find `numpy`, yet according to pip from the command line it was installed in the pyenv-venv.

Turns out I had the directory using an older pyenv-venv (3.8.12) on the command line, that had the pip packages installed. Yet VSCode was using a newer pyenv-venv (3.10.6) which I had forgotten to install `numpy` into.

So, to match what VSCode was set to, and the one I thought I was using...

```
pyenv local venv_3.10.6
pip install matplotlib
```

fixed it. Now Test Explorer was able to discover the unittests correctly.